# reducing I/O on application and database

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, mysql

Is there a way to reduce the I/O's associated with either mysql or a python script?  I am thinking of using EC2 and the costs seem okay except I can't really predict my I/O usage and I am worried it might blindside me with costs.

I basically develop a python script to parse data and upload it into mysql.  Once its in mysql, I do some fairly heavy analytic on it(creating new columns, tables..basically alot of math and financial based analysis on a large dataset). So is there any design best practices to avoid heavy I/O's?  I think memcached stores a everything in memory and accesses it from there, is there a way to get mysql or other scripts to do the same?

I am running the scripts fine right now on another host with 2 gigs of ram, but the ec2 instance I was looking at had about 8 gigs so I was wondering if I could use the extra memory to save me some money.

Comment: how big is your *large data set*?, will it fit into memory?

Comment: Hi Chris..yes I should have mentioned that it should fit.  My plan is my dataset will be maybe 2-3 gigs with really nothing else running on the box.  If there is a solution that works, I can really keep upgrading my memory to keep up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By IO I assume you mean disk IO... and assuming you can fit everything into memory **comfortably**. You could:

- Disable swap on your box†
- Use mysql [MEMORY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/memory-storage-engine.html) tables while you are processing, (or perhaps consider using an [Sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) in memory store if you are only using the database for the convenience of SQL queries)

Also: unless you are using EBS I didn't think Amazon charged for IO on your instance. EBS is much slower than your instance storage so only use it when you *need* the persistance, ie. not while you are crunching data.

†probably bad idea

Comment: I doubt that disabling swap will decrease disk I/O ... Although this may depend on your OS ... But what doesn't depend on your OS is that disabling swap means your applications will **crash** when you run out memory ... IMHO it's not a good idea ... If your system uses a lot of swap space, add more memory. Or add faster (SSD) swap ... But don't disable it, it's there for a reason ;-)

Comment: You're not wrong about it crashing!, I was just going for maximum effect... point two alone would be more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really specify whether it was writes or reads. My guess is that you can do it all in a mysql instance in a ramdisc (tmpfs under Linux).

Operations such as ALTER TABLE and copying big data around end up creating a lot of IO requests because they move a lot of data. This is not the same as if you've just got a lot of random (or more predictable queries).

If it's a batch operation, maybe you can do it entirely in a tmpfs instance.

It is possible to run more than one mysql instance on the machine, it's pretty easy to start up an instance on a tmpfs - just use mysql_install_db with datadir in a tmpfs, then run mysqld with appropriate params. Stick that in some shell scripts and you'll get it to start up. As it's in a ramfs, it won't need to use much memory for its buffers - just set them fairly small.